# How to choose the data to replace the missing values i the dataset

Tags: data-science, data-manipulation

i like to know the approach we take for data imputation in the dataset.i have missing values in the data set . what method and on what basis we choose to replace the na values i the dataset

Comment: Can you describe the problem more? How does your dataset look like? What is the nature of the missing value (discrete/continuous...)? What are you trying to do with the dataset? Are you training an ML model? What model?

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply.actually am trying to build the ml algorithm over the dataset. i generally didnt expect the exact solution to data imputation. am asking for generic approach we should have towartds the data imputation the things we need to consider

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you exactly what to do without knowing the data you are actually dealing with... But I assume `wildcard` package in R is very helpful.

Please take a look at [this official document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wildcard/wildcard.pdf) if you are using R to manipulate data.

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply.actually am trying to build the ml algorithm over the dataset. i generally didnt expect the exact solution to data imputation. am asking for generic approach we should have towartds the data imputation the things we need to consider